# How to move aim in games by using Python

Tags: python, auto, aim

I'm trying to create an AI that plays CS:GO.

But I could not move aim.

I tried pyautogui, win32api, pynput libraries, all of them worked on desktop or anywhere that have an cursor.

But in game there is no cursor and as I followed position of mouse is stay at middle ((1920/2, 1080/2), for me) when move mouse to turn it increases for a short time then backs to that position.

How can I move aim in CS:GO or GTAV or anygame by python. what is the difference between python code and real mouse?

I do not think this is because of anti-cheat because it did not worked on GTAV

I looked same topics but they did not solve my problem

Codes where similar for all libraries so the code that I used is this:

```
import pyautogui, sys
import _thread
import time

time.sleep(2)

def kaydir(miktarX, miktarY):
    pyautogui.moveRel(miktarX, miktarY)

print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
        _thread.start_new_thread(kaydir, (1, 1))
        time.sleep(0.08)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Please post some code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So first thing is: What do you mean with that question:

> what is the difference between python code and real mouse?

But if you want to create an bot for any game you have 2 options:

- Memory Hacking:
   Get some memory pointers to change input flags etc (via CheatEngine etc)
- Simulating user interaction (your way):
   If you want to use PyAutoGUI for interaction i think this is a good point to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaZTtUmE990

  Another way, I would prefer, is (as you have mentioned) the WinAPI:
   C++ implementation for mouse moving (since i dont know how to do it in python):

  ```c++
  int main() {
      HWND tWin= FindWindow("TargetWindow", "Target Window");
      if (tWin) {
          RECT rect = {0};
          GetWindowRect(tWin, &rect);
          SetCursorPos(rect.right - 180 /*x offset*/, rect.bottom - 300 /*y offset*/);
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  Also make sure that if your program is **64-bit** use the **64-bit WinAPI**.

  If your game is running under higher privilegies as you bot you need to run your   bot as Administrator or as SYSTEM

  But I think to create a bot **you also need memory hacking** (just reading) for getting the player position etc, **Since how do you extract pos items etc from the gamescreen-imgage from the programmers point of view?**. You may also can also use Machine Learning but for a game it needs a huge training process.

Comment: My fault. I tried to say why i can move aim with my mouse but not with python functions like pyautogui.moveRel()

I read frame from game and produce some output according to that. 
here is my problem is more clear: https://youtu.be/QWkFIP4GoYU seconds to start 22

Comment: It looks like you first have to **click** into the CS:GO window to get the **focus** before moving the mouse